# How long does it take for a user to be fully deleted in Softlayer?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, user-management

When you try to delete a user in SoftLayer (either via the portal or the API), the user is put into a 'cancel pending' state. They will not show up in the users list, and cannot login. However, you if you try to create a new user with the same email address, the system will render this message: `This username already exists in the system.`

How long does it take until the user is fully deleted and that email can be used again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you delete an user it only changes its status, it is never deleted from the database, Softlayer wants to keep it for tracking reasons, because that particular user could have created resources in the account such as servers, VLans etc, so softlayer does not want to lose that information.

However this behavior will be modified currenlty Softlayer is working on that in order you can be able to create a new user with the mail that you deleted user had.

Regards

Comment: According to this, they do delete users, but it doesn't specify how long it takes. But there must be some time range, at least. https://github.com/softlayer/terraform-provider-softlayer/blob/master/docs/resources/softlayer_user.md#additional-notes

Comment: The user is deleted never, in order to allow create a new user with the same email as a deleted user they are planning to change the username of the deleted user. Probably they documented like that because they were thinking adding the functionality to create new users with the same email, but currently that functionaly is in development. There is a jira created for that, but there is not a ETA I estimate it wil be released in a couple a weeks.